# Show and hide line chart highlight on touch

Tags: ios-charts

I want to only highlight a data point when the finger is on the chart, as soon as it lifts off the screen I want to call, or simple deselect the highlight.

```
func chartValueNothingSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase) {
    print("Nothing Selected")
    markerView.hidden = true
}
```

I've tried to override the touch ended but haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 8):

You can turn off highlighting any bars/data all together using the `highlightEnabled` property.

Example of this is:

```
barChartView.data?.highlightEnabled = false
```

---

If you still want to be able to highlight values, but want them to automatically deselect after the touch has ended, I also found another function `highlightValues(highs: [ChartHighlight]?)` which says in the documentation..

> Provide null or an empty array to undo all highlighting.

Call this when you want to deselect all the values and I believe this will work. Example of this could be:

```
let emptyVals = [ChartHighlight]()  
barChartView.highlightValues(emptyVals)
```

Ref:
[Charts Docs: highlightValues documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Charts/2.2.5/Classes/ChartViewBase.html#/s:FC6Charts13ChartViewBase15highlightValuesFGSqGSaCS_14ChartHighlight__T_)

Comment: This is great and I also stumbled upon this too, however I haven't be able to find where I can override the touch handler or specifically just determine when touch has ended in regards to the Chart view. Any resource or help related to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to do anything with the tapped data you can use:

```
barChartView.data?.highlightEnabled = false
```

If you want to use the tapped data point without displaying the highlight lines, you can use the selection delegate (don't forget to add `ChartViewDelegate` to your class):

```
yourChartView.delegate = self // setup the delegate
```

Add delegate function:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
  // do something with the selected data entry here

  yourChartView.highlightValue(nil) // deselect selected data point
}
```